# Python: Check if a key in a dictionary is contained in a string in a list

Tags: python, string, dictionary, parsing

I need to parse a list that has strings in each index and count each time a certain word is hit.

```
    pesc = 0 
    herbivore = 0
    vegan = 0
    food_dict = {'fish':'pesc', 'meat':'herbivore','plant':'vegan','chicken':'herbivore'}
    PeopleDiet = ['momeatschickenandavideatsfish','dadwilleatsplantandchicken','brotherlikestoeatfishandmeat']
```

```
    for key in food_dict.keys():
        for i in PeopleDiet:
           if str(key) in PeopleDiet[i]:
             pesc = pesc+1
             plant = plant +1
             herbivore = herbivore +1
             print(index)
             print(pesc)
             print(plant)
             print(herbivore)
```

Right now the code doesn't output anything, but ideally
I would want something like for each index:

> > herbivore = 1,fish = 1, for index 1
> > vegan= 1 , herbivore =1, for index 2
> > pesc =1, herbivore =1  for index 3

Any help would be great! Thank you so much

Comment: Try writing out what you intend for each line of the code to do, in plain English words, and then see if it makes sense. If it doesn't make sense, fix that first. If it does, then try to figure out what part of the code doesn't do what you expect it to. Please also read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 2):

The line `for i in PeopleDiet` is already looping over all the *strings*, not the indices, so `PeopleDiet[i]` doesn't make sense. You want to check if:

`key in i`

Cleaning up your code a little:

```py
    for key in food_dict:
        for idx, elem in enumerate(PeopleDiet):
           if key in elem:
             print(...)
```

Here, `idx` will be the index for each element `elem` in the list `PeopleDiet`

Answer (score 1):

When you run `for i in PeopleDiet:`, `i` is string type in `PeopleDiet`, it will cause error because you want to fetch a value by doing `PeopleDiet[string type]`.

Based on something you want:

> herbivore = 1,fish = 1, for index 1...

which is confused that the output should be either the key `'fish'` or the value `'herbivore'` in the `food_dict`...

To address your exception, the code could be :

```
food_dict = {'fish':'pesc', 'meat':'herbivore','plant':'vegan','chicken':'herbivore'}
PeopleDiet = ['momeatschickenandavideatsfish','dadwilleatsplantandchicken','brotherlikestoeatfishandmeat']
i = 0
while PeopleDiet:
    string = PeopleDiet.pop()
    for f in food_dict.keys():
        if f in string:
            print('for index = {0}, {1} = 1 ('.format(i, food_dict[f]), f, 'hits in "{}"'.format(string), ')')
    i += 1
```

and the output:

```
for index = 0, pesc = 1 ( fish hits in "brotherlikestoeatfishandmeat" )
for index = 0, herbivore = 1 ( meat hits in "brotherlikestoeatfishandmeat" )
for index = 1, vegan = 1 ( plant hits in "dadwilleatsplantandchicken" )
for index = 1, herbivore = 1 ( chicken hits in "dadwilleatsplantandchicken" )
for index = 2, pesc = 1 ( fish hits in "momeatschickenandavideatsfish" )
for index = 2, herbivore = 1 ( meat hits in "momeatschickenandavideatsfish" )
for index = 2, herbivore = 1 ( chicken hits in "momeatschickenandavideatsfish" )
```